# Is there an abstract list subclass with magic methods that return an instance of further subclassed type

Tags: python, list, inheritance

This would not be hard to implement, but I have to ask if there exists a standard list subclass, that is more appropriate for inheritance than the pure list object. By that I mean an object with magic methods defined like in the following code.

```py
class AbstractList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        item = super().__getitem__(i)
        if isinstance(item, int): return item
        else: return type(self)(item)
```

Superclassing this kind of class, instead of list, would spare me some additional code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `collections.abc` module includes Abstract Base Classes that require only little customisation. [`collections.abc.MutableSequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableSequence) is the ABC closest to a `list` - you have to override `__delitem__`, `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__len__`, and `insert`. Other magic methods, such as `__iter__`, will use these as required.

```
class MyList(collections.abc.MutableSequence):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._data = list(*args, **kwargs)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)

    def __delitem__(self, item):
        del self._data[item]

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._data[item]

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        self._data[item] = value

    def insert(self, i, x):
        self._data.insert(i, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`collections.UserList`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList) exists for this exact purpose, though it does not inherit from `list` - it's more like a python re-implementation of the `list` builtin.

Comment: Tried this, but calling `__getitem__` on a subClass(UserList) again returns an object of type list instead of subClass

Comment: @kuco23 I can not reproduce that. Slicing a `UserList` returns another `UserList`. Maybe your subclass messed something up?